# file cannot create directory using xcode on mac

Tags: xcode, macos, opencv

I am now compiling opencv source codes based on instructions in [How to Build OpenCV Static Libraries Mac OS X](http://shiffman.net/2011/01/23/how-to-build-opencv-static-libraries-mac-os-x/). I have no problem with creating xcode project with CMake, and compilation goes on well. I can see that static libraries have been created. However, when I use the install function of the project, I receive the following errors:

```
/Applications/CMake\ 2.8-11.app/Contents/bin/cmake -DBUILD_TYPE=Debug -P cmake_install.cmake


-- Install configuration: "Debug"


CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:31 (FILE):


  file cannot create directory: /usr/local/include/opencv2.  Maybe need


  administrative privileges.
```

Any ideas on making installation possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following command to make installation succeed:

```
 cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/  
  sudo ./Xcode /Users/***/Desktop/directory_name/open_source/opencv/xcode/OpenCV.xcodeproj
```